# Binding doesnt work for GridViewColumn Width property

Tags: c#, wpf, gridviewcolumn

I set an one way binding to `Width` property of `GridViewColumn`.At 1st time it gets value from binding and **sets it to `Width` property**.When source is changed it gets value from binding, but it **doesnt set** to `Width` property.What to do ?
Here is code

`<GridViewColumn Width="{Binding MaxWidthForTypeColumn}" >`

I dont know clearly,maybe it is set,but no change in `GridViewColumn`.

```
public int MaxWidthForTypeColumn
    {
        get
        {
            if (suggestions.Count != 0)
            {
                var max = from elemnt in suggestions
                          select elemnt.TypeInfo.Length;
                int x = max.Max();
                return x + 100;
            }
            else
                return 20;
        }

    }
```

i call event from other property

[EDIT] This is bug as bug in ListViewItem width property

Comment: what is the 'MaxWidthForTypeColumn'? to width of which control do you binding?

Comment: I use MVVM.This is property of object which is DataContext

Comment: Have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged to notify binding that property has been changed?

Comment: Yes,i said that it gets value,but doesnt set.I put breakpoint to see that,and see that property  is gotten ,but no change

Comment: Can you show code of your property? and is this XAML complete?

Comment: i found that, there is bug in this type of problems. Microsoft said that they will solve this type of bugs, in next release